# Non-greedy method of partitioning numbers

Tags: summation, proof-writing, algorithms, computer-science, integer-partitions

I want to find an example of where a non-greedy method of partitioning numbers is better than the greedy method. The greedy method would be to partition them so that you group as many numbers as possible with their sum being less than or equal to the threshold.

e.g. greedy method : 11 + 1| 9 + 2 + 2 | 3 + 5 where the threshold is 13

```
non greedy method: 11 | 1 + 9 + 2 | 2 + 3 + 5
```

I am trying to think of an example where the non-greedy method would use less partitions than the greedy method. Please help!

Comment: The problem you describe is commonly called bin packing and is known to be NP-complete. Greedy methods do not reach an optimal in general, so without any constraints on the type of method you want, testing every possible partitions is a non-greedy method that performs better than greedy methods. Also if anyone knew of an efficient method to compute these optimal bin packing, that person would probably be claiming a million dollars instead of sharing the solution.

Comment: @N.Bach I am still having trouble finding an example where the non-greedy method packs with less bins than the greedy method.. Do you have any examples that you could share?

Comment: Threshold 10, numbers: 4, 4, 6, 6. The classic greedy algorithm first-fit will pack 3 bins 4+4, 6, 6, but the optimal uses 2 bins 4+6 and 4+6.

Comment: The "*non-greedy method*" is still a greedy algorithm: it's just a less sophisticated one than the one you call "*the*" greedy method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you refer to is called **bin packing**, and it's been extensively studied for its great practical importance. In fact, bin packing was the first problem for which the issue of "greedy vs. non-greedy" was studied. The standard terminology for it is "**online** vs. **offline**": informally, online algorithms are ones that "accomodate" the input as it arrives, instead of waiting until they know it all to make their decisions. A crucial measure of the quality of an online algorithm is its **competitive ratio**: roughly speaking, the worst case ratio between the cost it incurs (for bin packing, the number of bins) and the lowest cost one could possibly incur, as the latter tends to infinity.

For bin packing, the [lower bound on the competitive ratio is known to be more than 1.54](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82468406.pdf); and there are [complicated online algorithms that manage a competitive ratio below 1.58](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01728.pdf). I'd note that it's significantly easier to manage a competitive ratio of 1.6, and very very, easy to manage 2.